# how to turn associative array into function parameters in php

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to turn an associative array into parameters for a function.

I have a simply array such:

```
$arr = [
  'id' => 321654,
  'name' => 'action1'
];
```

I have a static function in a class:

```
class someclass{
  static function someFunction( $id, $name ){
     //the rest of the method
  }
}
```

I can call the class by variables, eg:

```
$class = 'someclass';
$method = 'somFunction';

return $class::$method(  );
```

I can also pass is in a definite qty of function parameters, or an array

```
return $class::$method( $arr );
```

In this example's case I could hard code the params to:

```
return $class::$method( $arr['id'], $arr['name'] );
```

But how would i pass an unknown qty of keys. Another run may contain 1 key or 4 or 10...

Comment: Which PHP  version are you using?

Comment: Take a look at `call_user_func_array`

Comment: I think @Rizier123 possibly meant `func_get_args` - either way check here http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Comment: ``return call_user_func_array( ''.$class.'::'.$method, $params );``  Worked a charm. Adding to Q

Comment: @John Yey, you got the solution! But please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer answers in the answer section :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Rizier123 comment:

This worked very nicely:

```
call_user_func_array( ''.$class.'::'.$method, $arr );
```